# Search Nth field in each line for string, then append a value to end of each line

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a shell script to analyze input files and send results to output files. Here is a sample from an input file:

```
01,Rome,30,New York,70,
02,Los Angeles,5,New York,50,
03,New York,40,Tokyo,20,
04,Paris,5,New York,40,
05,New York,20,London,30,
06,Seattle,20,New York,40,
07,Chicago,10,New York,30,
08,New York,20,Miami,40,
```

This is the result I need in an output file:

```
01,Rome,30,New York,70,4th,40,
02,Los Angeles,5,New York,50,4th,45,
03,New York,40,Tokyo,20,2nd,20,
04,Paris,5,New York,40,4th,35,
05,New York,20,London,30,2nd,-10,
06,Seattle,20,New York,40,4th,20,
07,Chicago,10,New York,30,4th,20,
08,New York,20,Miami,40,2nd,-20,
```

Fields are separated by commas.

I intend to search the second field of each line for the string "New York" and if true, add a 6th field with "2nd" and if not true add a 6th field with a value of "4th"

Then I intend to preform subtraction using the values in the 3rd and 5th fields. If the string in the 6th field is "4th," subtract 3rd field from 5th field. If the string in the 6th field is "2nd," subtract the 5th field from the 3rd field. The result of the calculation needs to be the 7th field in each line.

I have tried combinations of awk, sed, grep, echo and bc, but I feel I am overthinking things. Any suggestions?

Edit: My progress thus far - I was thinking that evaluating and appending each line individually would be inefficient.

```
    while read line; do 
         echo "$(cut -f2 -d ",")"
    done < input.txt
```

prints the second field of each line, but I am stumped on evaluating the strings and appending the lines within the loop. For the subtraction part, my plan was to use echo and pipe values to bc, but I am stuck on the first step at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: This looks like an easy job for awk. Use `,` comma as field separator, then writing column compares `if ($2 = "New York") { $6 = "2nd" } else { $6 = "4th" }` looks simple and easy.

Comment: @KamilCuk indeed awk seems easiest. `awk -F "," '{if ($2 == "New York") { $6 = "2nd" } else { $6 = "4th" } print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6"," }' input.txt` worked for me on the first part. As to the subtraction part, is it possible to set multiple variables within an if statement?  I attempted `awk -F "," '{if ($2 == "New York") { $6 = "2nd" && NYpoints=$3 && OtherPoints=$5 } else { $6 = "4th" && NYpoints=$5 && OtherPoints=$3 } print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","($NYpoints - $OtherPoints) }' input.txt` but that changes the 6th field to an integer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First replace those spaces in your file because it will be easier to work

```
cat inputfile | sed 's/ /_/g' > tmp && mv tmp inputfile
```

Then define a test variable:

```
test=New_York
```

Now the main process:

```
for i in $(cat inputfile)
do
  if [[ $(echo "$i" | cut -d',' -f2) == "$test" ]]
  then
    int1=$(echo "$i" | cut -d',' -f5)
    int2=$(echo "$i" | cut -d',' -f3)
    result=$(expr "$int2" - "$int1")
    echo $i | sed "s/$/2nd,$result/g" >> outputfile
  else
    int1=$(echo "$i" | cut -d',' -f3)
    int2=$(echo "$i" | cut -d',' -f5)
    result=$(expr "$int2" - "$int1")
    echo $i | sed "s/$/4th,$result/g" >> outputfile
  fi
done
```

If you want to put the spaces back in the file:

```
cat outputfile | sed 's/_/ /g' > tmp && mv tmp outputfile
```

Comment: When you do want to use a loop (you shouldn't), use `while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5; do .. done < inputfile`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this method.

Comment: I figured you wanted to practice using a conditional statement or something along those lines. c:

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 0):

I think `awk` is the easiest job, here an alterative using `sed` :

```
sed -r 's/.*,New York,([0-9]*),.*,([0-9]*),/echo "&2nd,$((\1 - \2))"/e; 
        s/.*,.*,([0-9]*),New York,([0-9]*),/echo "&4th,$((\2 - \1))"/e' input.txt
```

EDIT, Explanation:
When you change `/e;` into `/;` and remove the last `e` you can see better what is happening.
The input line with New York as the second field is matched in parts:

```
.*,       # First field. It will not eat the whole line, because
          # the rest of the line must match too. 
New York, # Match on the second field
([0-9]*), # The match on the number in parentheses, so it can be used later.
.*,       # next field
([0-9]*), # Second string to remember. I edited the answer, first I had `([0-9]*).`
          # what worked (`.` is a wildcard), but `,` is better.
```

For doing the calculation, we need the shell. The shell can do calculations without `bc` using something like `echo "$((8 - 5))"`. 
The replacement string will be something that can be executed.

```
echo "..." # Command to echo the things in quotes
&          # Replace with the complete match, in our case the complete line
2nd,       # Nothing special here.
$((...))   # Perform calculation
\1         # Replace with first remembered match (between parentheses)
\2         # Replace with second remembered match (between parentheses)
```

`sed` supports `/e` for executing the result. (Do not try to set a variable with `/e`, it will be executed in a subshell and the variable is lost after execution).
The above construction is repeated for New York as the fourth field.